# Bootstrap - Change col-xs value

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with **Bootstrap**. Depending on the orientation (portrait or landscape in mobile device), the value of col-xs-* is not the same.

**Example** :

```
// If Orientation landscape
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6"></div>
// If Orientation portrait
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
```

How can I do in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you should replace both these lines with simply:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
```

...or is that not granular enough for you?

Comment: ...sorry I am not following you. Can you post your code in full please